# How do I d/l qBittorrent at the Ubuntu app site?

Tags: software-center

I see no download button.  I submitted my email but it just linked me back to the same app page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install applications in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu)

Comment: I for one am unclear as to what you mean by "the Ubuntu app site"? Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

Open the Ubuntu Software Center, search for qBittorrent, click qBittorrent in the search results to select it, click the button that says *More Info* and then click the button marked by the mouse pointer in the screenshot below that says *Install* to install it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too sure whether you're exactly referring to the software center or a website as the tag & title confuses me. Also, there's a default client named **Transmission** for torrent downloads; you may make a use of it for such needs. Just do a simple search from the Ubuntu dash home (seen below;)

[image]

Nevertheless, **qBittorent** app should be visible for download on software center as the official repositories are there from **Ubuntu 9.04 "Jaunty"** onward. Below a screen where you'll just need to click on install to proceed further.

[image]

Else you may download more up-to-date packages using **PPAs**. To do so, you can do below;

- Firstly open a terminal (press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
- And then type below commands to add PPAs (Use either one of the above as you prefer)

> **qBittorrent Stable**
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hydr0g3n/qbittorrent-stable
> ```
>
> **or qBittorrent Unstable**
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hydr0g3n/qbittorrent-trunk
> ```

- Type below to install

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install qbittorrent
```

Answer (score 0):

If by the Ubuntu app site you mean [Ubuntu Package Search.](https://packages.ubuntu.com/)

Simply search for the package you want (qbittorrent) as seen below selecting the distribution that you are looking for. Select the exact hit and you can select Download the source package and then choose the specific source file to download (you will need to compile it)

**A far easier method would be to simply** [add the Universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) and then issue the command `sudo apt-get install qbittorrent`

[image]